# How to relate INSERTED and DELETED columns in INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql

We have an INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE trigger on a view migrating it from Oracle. It inserts or updates data in underlying table of the view instead of the view. Furthermore, for any insert on the view it updates rather than insert if an id in the table matches with the insert id. So, if multiple entries are thrown at table some will have new entries while matching ids will have an update. The trigger also uses an cursor on an inserted tables to mimic Oracle's FOR EACH ROW.

Now the problem, we want to update some values in the inserting/updating rows based on new values (inserting/updating), old values (deleting) or assign a value if both of these values do not satisfy. Underlying table does not have any PK. How can we join INSERTED and DELETED tables so that we can refer NEW and OLD values for each column in each updating row ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSTEAD_OF_TRG ON VIEW V
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN

DECLARE INSERTED_CUR CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE, MODIFIEDDATE

DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(6), NAME VARCHAR(50), VALUE VARCHAR(10), MODIFIEDDATE DATETIME2

FETCH NEXT FROM INSERTED_CUR INTO @ID, @NAME, @VALUE, @MODIFIEDDATE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

DECLARE @LVALUE VARCHAR(10)

-- HERE WE WANT TO CHECK FOR NEW AND UPDATED VALUES OF COLUMN VALUE

IF @VALUE IS NOT NULL --- VALUE FROM INSERTED IS NOT NULL
SET @LVALUE = @VALUE
ELSE 
**IF @OLDVALUE IS NOT NULL  
SET @LVALUE = @OLDVALUE**
-- HOW CAN WE REFER OLD VALUE HERE IN CASE OF UPDATES. IN ORACLE THEY ARE DOING IT LIKE :NEW.VALUE IN FIRST IF AND :OLD.VALUE IN ELSE IF FOR EACH ROW.

SET @LVALUE = @OLDVALUE
ELSE
SET @LVALUE = 'DEFAULT'


-- UPDATE AND INSERT CODE CONTINUES WHERE WE USE @LVALUE--
```

Comment: For the `INSERT` case - `Inserted` will contain the new values being inserted. For the `UPDATE` case, the `Inserted` will contain the new values (after the update), while `Deleted` will contain the "old" values - before the update was applied. In order to "link" those two pseudo tables - you ***MUST USE*** the primary key of those tables involved - yet another reason why ***EVERY*** serious table must have a well defined primary key ....

Comment: And another word of advice - in a SQL Server trigger - ***never ever*** use a cursor! That's a sure fire way to kill off any performance in your system. You need to handle the potentially multiple rows in a proper, set-based fashion.

Comment: Only you know what makes a unique join between inserted and deleted, with no PK, as already said, that has the potential to cause issues.

Comment: @marc_s Yes agree with the cursor part. We tried to convert to set based operation but the combination of inserts and updates is not working with it.

Comment: @DaleK I think we will have introduce a primary key and make a join based on it. Thanks.

Comment: Another recommendation: have separate triggers for the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` case. Yes - you'll have two triggers - but each will be so much easier since you don't have to constantly check whether you're in insert or update mode .....